# Qual a diferença entre Class e Code File no asp.net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Qual a diferença entre Class e Code File no asp.net Core?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existem dois tipo de arquivos no asp.net core, tem alguma diferença entre um e outro?

E quando devemos usar cada um?

Comment: Não é apenas no asp.net core, o codefile.cs é criado com o build action `Content`, ao invés de `Compile` da classe comum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A opção "Class" gera um arquivo de código C# com uma estrutura básica de classe, assim:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Class1
    {
    }
}
```

Já a opção "Code File" gera um arquivo de código fonte vazio, onde você tem que escrever tudo do zero. Na prática a única diferença é template usado na primeira.